# Not able to install ag-grid-enterprise using bower

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

We have the license to use ag-grid-enterprise. We are trying to install it using bower and using with angular 1.2.19

After installation, it is referring to ag-grid-enterprise/main.js rather than ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js.

Please let us know where it can go wrong and if we are using the correct package for supporting angularjs.

[image: rendered html from developer tools]

[image: loaded resources from developer tools]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the bundled version of ag-Grid Enterprise - for example:

bower_components/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.

```
<script src="../bower_components/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js"></script>
```

Here you can use ag-grid-enterprise.js or ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js etc

Please see https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-more-details/ "Bundle Types" for more information